# Open modal window components

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components

What is the best way to open some components in modal window,for example while editing one sale I can open a modal for other secondary data
like adding new cities/client name and not leaving sale window?
 I can navigate to edit/add  component with router like this

```
this.router.navigate(['/edit-city']);
```

but this will leave main data window
I need a behavior like .NET/C#  winforms  .ShowDialog()

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found [Angular-custom-modal](https://github.com/zurfyx/angular-custom-modal) that supports components inside modal and also create +destroy it when modal is shown/closed